# Тормозит apache - не пойму почему

Tags: apache

Итак, есть VPS - операционка centos, на ней apache и сайты на джумле

Что-то все сайты очень тормозят и открываются по полминуты.

Джумлу, mysql, php - всё исключаю т.к. тормозит даже если напрямую url картинки вызвать - картинка отзывается через секунд 20

Нагрузку на сервер тоже исключаю - как-то так

```
    load average: 0.00, 0.02, 0.01
Tasks: 217 total,   1 running, 216 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.0%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2097152k total,   739160k used,  1357992k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   728556k cached
```

Проблему площадки пусть тоже исключим - техподдержка говорит всё ОК

Получается тормозит Апач?

Как найти почему именно?

UPD В-общем проблема как-то локализована, оказалось один из сайтов постоянно обращался сам к себе, его временно выключили. Но хостер наверное таки жадничать начал на ресурсах, раньше всё было также и всё работало

Comment: А iostat что говорит? Возможно слишком интенсивное обращение к жесткому диску?

Comment: iostat не ставил - по фтп всё летает и wa 0%, это ведь позволяет сказать что с жёстким всё ок?

Comment: С самим диском возможно все не плохо, однако, процессы могут чего-то ждать, например, доступа к диску или к сети или ответа от базы данных. Посмотрите, кстати, список соединений в MySQL -  с ними все в порядке, их не много? Воможно часть запросов блокированы и ждут освобождения блокировки.

Comment: даже если напрямую url картинки вызвать - картинка отзывается через секунд 20 - разве это не исключает проблемы с mysql ?

Comment: Кстати вот ещё какие симптомы забыл изложить:
1) проблема началась на ровном месте - никто ничего не менял и в настройках не лазил.
2) если перезагрузить VPS - первые пару минут всё работает хорошо, а потом опять начинается

Comment: Ещё инфа - FTP летает, phpmyadmin тормозит, картинки по прямому урлу тормозят (это уже писал кажется, ещё раз обращаю внимание)

Comment: @Alexander111136 Пожалуйста, обновляйте вопрос для добавления дополнительной информации, вместо публикации комментариев.